# Setting POSIX permissions at file creation time in Java

Tags: java, file, posix

Is there a way to create a file with a given set of POSIX permissions?

It's possible to set POSIX permissions for a file once the file exists. The code below does this. However, that code also has a file race in which the file is opened with what can be loose permissions (CREATION) which I then lock down later (SECURED). In between someone could have modified the file, causing problems. How can I set permissions at creation time?

```
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = 
             EnumSet.of(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ, 
                        PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);       
    Path targetPath = dir.resolve(FILENAME);
    String contents = getContent();
    try {//  CREATION, race starts
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempPath.toFile())) {
            fw.append(contents);
        }
        //  SECURED, race ends
        Files.setPosixFilePermissions(tempPath, perms);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's another POSIX interface: [PosixFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html) and you can pass it to Files.createFile()

See the section [Setting Intial Permissions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html):

> Setting Initial Permissions
>
> ```
> Implementations supporting this attribute view may also 
> support setting the initial permissions when creating a file or directory.
> ```

Passing the below Path to the FileWriter does the right thing:

```
Path lockedFile = Files.createFile(tempPath,
                                  PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms));
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(lockedFile.toFile())) {
 ...
```